# Why does this `word-wrap: break-word` rule not work as expected in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, width, word-wrap, word-break

Why does a `word-wrap: break-word` CSS rule not shrink an element in Firefox, when the corresponding rule works in Chrome?

The `.form-field` container here is constrained to 300px width, and the `legend` inside it has a 100% width. The long words inside stretch the `legend` out to overflow the 300px width.

When I apply the CSS `break-word` rule to Chrome using the (non-standard) WebKit `word-break` definition, the long word is broken and the `legend` element shrinks to the expected width of 300px.

In Firefox, the corresponding `word-wrap` rule doesn't break the text and shrink the element unless I specifically set the width of the `legend` to 300px. Why do I have to do that? Why doesn't Firefox make the "100% of 300px" calculation and size the `legend` correctly?

If you view this snippet on Firefox, you'll see that the `legend` still overflows the 300px width of its container.

[image]

```css
.form-field {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  outline: 1px solid purple;
}

.form-field legend {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.form-field input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #c8d7e1;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-field">
  <legend>Betweenthesetwo, InowfeltIhadtochoose. Mytwonatureshadmemoryincommonbutallotherfacultiesweremostunequallysharedbetweenthem.</legend>
  <input type="text">
</fieldset>
```

(Tested in macOS Chrome 64 and Firefox 57).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `break-word` of `word-break` is not supported in Firefox. Check the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) and you will see this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @temani-afif, it's confusing, the MDN documentation for `overflow-wrap` implies `overflow-wrap: break-word` is supported in FF. And similarly https://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap implies FF supports the synonymous rule `word-wrap: break-word`. If that's true, how come the `word-wrap` rule isn't working?

Comment: Thanks @temani-afif, that link's exactly what I needed, very useful! Maybe your answer should be tweaked to emphasise that the problem is not with the `word-wrap` rule but with FF's treatment of `fieldset`.

Comment: @AndFinally yes that's it :) you only have issue with break-word with firefox ;)

Answer (score 0):

Update CSS of legend

```
.form-field legend {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all; // Modified 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All we need is

```
word-break: break-all;
```